# How to mount an afp shared folder in Debian Linux as a volume?

Tags: linux, debian, afp

I have some shared folders in my Mac that I wish to access from my Debian 10. I have researched some solutions to mount it as a volume, this will be good.

I found Netatalk that seems powerful but the tutorials I saw was to turn my Debian into a Time Machine... I also found afpns-fg, but the GitHub is archived, it seems abandoned for many years... I look at Snapcraft, Google, but didn't find any afp client... I am out of Ideas... can you help me?

Comment: Right now I am using smb/cifs by cifs-utils package. Would be interesting to know how to do it by afp. I found afpfs-ng but no documentation of how to use it, seems abandoned since 2015...

Answer (score 1):

I have recently worked to find how to mount AFP share (from a NAS).
First, my afpfs-ng package refers to [this website](https://sites.google.com/site/alexthepuffin/) which gives everything you need.

You can find an example on how to mount the share using */etc/fstab* (boot time mount).
Here an additional example:

```
afpfs#afp://USER:PASS@SERVER/SHARE    /mnt/afp    fuse    user=USER,group=GROUP,_netdev    0    0
```

As stated in the previous link, there is another command `afpcmd` that is a simple client (no mounting). Finally, you can also use `mount_afp`:

```
mount_afp afp://USER:PASS@SERVER/SHARE /mnt/afp/
```

(Although, I am actually facing performance issue using `afpfs_ng`.)

It is also possible to use the graphical user interface to mount an AFP share. I saw it working with MATE and GNOME (thanks to `gvfs`). You just have to look in "Network" and the server will be presented.

Answer (score 1):

In short:

- Linux 5.15 [drops support for NTLM](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=76a3c92ec9e0668e4cd0e9ff1782eb68f61a179c). So you should either older kernel or recompile with reverted commit.

  ```bash
  sudo mount -rw -t cifs //mycapsule/Data /media/airport/ -o username=myuser,password=mypass,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 --verbose
  ```
- You may use `afpfs-ng` package from another disto (Ubuntu got rid of it since v14 or v15). I put deb-package from ArchLinux into Github repo https://github.com/maxx27/afpfs-ng-deb

  ```bash
  sudo mount_afp afp://myuser:mypass@mycapsule/Data /media/airport
  sudo umount /media/airport
  ```

For long instructions, see https://github.com/maxx27/afpfs-ng-deb